# TypeScript Interface not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

So right now, I'm trying to make a small modular web application. I am using typescript, which I am quite new to.

In my code, I:

- define the structure of an interface (`ProgramList`)
- I create an object with one property (`ProgramList`) of type `ProgramInfo`
- I define `ProgramList` with one array item using the `ProgramList` interface.

Here is my code:

```
interface ProgramInfo {
    path:string;
    name:string;
    pkgname:string[];
    start?:string[];
    cli?:string[];
}

let program = {
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[]
};

program.ProgramList = [
    {
        path: "/default_programs/WOSPMan",
        name: "WOSPMan (WebOS Package Manager)",
        pkgname: ["com", "webos", "wospman"],
        start: ["wospman", "wospm"],
        cli: ["wospman"]
    }
];
```

My IDE (JetBrains WebStorm), keeps giving me TypeScript Compile errors:

- `TS2304: Cannot find name`ProgramInfo`

although I clearly defined `ProgramInfo` on the first few lines.

Comment: how exactly do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
let program = {
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[]
};
```

You declare object `program` with property `ProgramList`. But you trying to assign array of interfaces to this property, it does not make sense. You can do like this:

```
let program: {ProgramList: ProgramInfo[]} = {
    ProgramList: []
};
```

Or like this:

```
interface Program {
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[];
}

let program: Program = {
    ProgramList: []
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let program = {
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[]
};
```

You're using an object literal here! Which means the double colon `:` doesn't mean `ProgramList` is of type `ProgramInfo[]`, but instead means assign `program.ProgramList` to the variable `ProgramInfo`, which of course doesn't exist.

What you should do instead is assign an empty Array to the `ProgramList` field.

```
let program = {
    ProgramList: []
};
```

If you're looking for more typesafety you could of course add an interface that describes your `program` object.

```
interface Program{
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
interface Program {
    ProgramList: ProgramInfo[]
}

let program: Program = {
    ProgramList: []
};
```